# EWS and Skype for Business/Lync meeting info

Tags: sip, exchangewebservices, skype-for-business

I am doing some work on Lync/Skype meeting integration. In order to make this work, I need to get hold of the GRUU/SIP information for events/meetings.

Currently I have some success by using EWS against Office365. I query for the `OnlineMeetingConfLink` extended property, and if the meeting is Skype-enabled, get the SIP.

However, when this meeting is forwarded to our own Exchange (2010 SP2), these properties are not added to the invitation. They are not present in any headers or anything.

The message body contains the Lync URL and Skype Conference ID, but those are not usable/parsable in a reliable way.

Any pointer to documentation or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: what do you mean by disappears?

Comment: they just aren't there.

Comment: Where? in the Graphical Interface? Be specific! Did you try fetching the extended property via Managed API and it still wasnt there?

Comment: I am talking about Exchange Web Services (EWS), as mentioned. First against Office365, then agains local Exchange. 
The client API is Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService..

On the other hand, I see that my question is probably wrong. When Exchange forwards the invitaion, there are no info about the Skype meeting in headers or anywhere else (except from the message body)